# Display custom org-entities as UTF-8 characters

Tags: org-mode

I've recently added some custom entries to my `org-entities-user` (below), but they do not display as UTF-8 characters, even with `org-toggle-pretty-entities` on. Is it because they are more than one UTF-8 character long? Any ideas how to change this behaviour?

```
(setq org-entities-user
      '(("dO" "\\(\\delta^{18}\\)O" nil "&delta;<sup>18</sup>O" "δ18O" "δ18O" "δ¹⁸O")
        ("eO" "\\({}^{18}\\)O" nil "<sup>18</sup>O" "18O" "18O" "¹⁸O")
        ("dC" "\\(\\delta^{13}\\)C" nil "&delta;<sup>13</sup>O" "δ13C" "δ¹³C" "δ¹³C")
        ("tC" "\\({}^{13}\\)C" nil "<sup>13</sup>C" "13C" "¹³C" "¹³O")
        ("COt" "CO\\(_{2}\\)" nil "CO<sub>2</sub>" "CO2" "CO₂" "CO₂")
        ("D" "\\Delta_{47}" t "&Delta;<sub>47</sub>" "Δ47" "Δ47" "Δ₄₇")
        ("celsius" "\\(^{\\circ}\\)C" nil "&deg;C" "°C" "°C" "°C")
        ;; unit space, something like 15\us{}Ma
        ("us" "\\," nil "&nbsp;" " " " " " ")
        ("appr" "\\sim" t "&tilde;" "~" "~" "~")
        ;; for gps-coordinates
        ("degree" "^{\\circ}" t "&deg;" "°" "°" "°")
        ("arcminute" "^{'}" t "&prime;" "'" "′" "′")
        ("arcsecond" "^{''}" t "&Prime;" "\"" "″" "″")
        ))
```

Answer (score 1):

Apparently, currently custom entities of more than one UTF-8 character are not previewed. I've submitted a [feature request](https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/emacs-orgmode/2018-12/msg00278.html) to the mailing list.